# How to pass data to a component while using Router.navigateByUrl

Tags: angular

I've an icon and on click of that icon I need to navigate to a different component. That component is neither parent nor child of the component from where the icon was originally clicked.

```
<i class="fa fa-times" (click)="iconClicked()"></i>
```

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
}

iconClicked() {
  this._router.navigateByUrl('/products/entity/record-page');
}
```

My requirement is to pass json data to that component. Let the json data be like this:

```
{
  name: "tanzeel",
  country: "india",
  hobbies: ["football","cricket","basketball"]
}
```

However in real scenario the json is going to be huge. How do I pass this json along with `this._router.navigateByUrl.....` to that component. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the data which you want to pass is static then you can use RC.4 router `data`.

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/component', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'component', component: YourComponent, data: {some_data: 'some value'}}
];
```

In the component, you can get data like below

```
class YourComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }
}
```

If the data that you want to pass is dynamic, then you should use a service which would store the data in first component before routing and then after routing it retrieves the data in Second Component.

Comment: the data is dynamic in my case. Actually first component shows list of all products and then on click on that icon it will redirect to detailed page of that product

Comment: I think you should handle this from backend then.
Make another api call for product details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `navigate` instead of navigateByUrl.
The syntax looks something like this:

```
this.router.navigate([ url ], { queryParams: your-json-data })
```

Angular docs: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate